# Reflection a new instance in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to reflection a new instance dynamically.
Here is my code :

```
let serviceTestCaseName = "NightlyTestStorageBlob";
```

and then create a new instance with this name.